# Read big file over serial

Tags: c#, serial-port, esp32

I'm new to serial programming and I read a lot of answer here on stackoverflow but none of those seems to fit correctly my scenario.

**SCENARIO**

I have an ESP32WROOM module that upon request sends over the serial port some bytes, the message is structured in that way:

First four bytes are the message length, next four bytes are the command, than the payload and the last byte of the message is the checksum of the streamed bytes. So, for example, it will look in this way:

```
MESSAGE LENGTH      COMMAND              PAYLOAD     CHECKSUM
0x00,0x00,0x02,0x05,0xBB,0xBB,0xBB,0xBB, .........., 0xCC
```

**MY ISSUE in C#**

Now the file that I'm trying to send over serial is a 5Mb file that my ESP32WROOM is downloading from internet, the file is sent over serial in chunks of 517 bytes (in the way that I stated above..message lenght, command etc etc..).

c# side I'm using

```
port_DataReceived
```

to listen for incoming transmission over serial and

```
buffer = new byte[port.BytesToRead];
port.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

to read from serial, **BUT** I'm not receiving all the 517bytes in one shot. I really can't understand what's going on, so please can anyone provides me any code to accomplish my task as I'm loosing hope?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a serial communication specification, it is not decided how many bytes should be received to notify the event.

[SerialPort.DataReceived Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

> Indicates that data has been received through a port represented by the SerialPort object.
>
> The DataReceived event is not guaranteed to be raised for every byte received. Use the BytesToRead property to determine how much data is left to be read in the buffer.

[SerialPort.BytesToRead Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.bytestoread?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

> Gets the number of bytes of data in the receive buffer.
>
> The receive buffer includes the serial driver's receive buffer as well as internal buffering in the SerialPort object itself.
> Because the BytesToRead property represents both the SerialPort buffer and the Windows-created buffer, it can return a greater value than the ReadBufferSize property, which represents only the Windows-created buffer.

Then, the number of bytes actually read by the Read method will be notified by the return value.

[SerialPort.Read Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.read?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

> Reads from the SerialPort input buffer.
>
> **Return Value**
> **Int32**
> The number of bytes read.

Make sure that the total received data is 517 bytes or more, and then cut out each 517 bytes and check the format.

If the received data or the remaining data after cutting is less than 517 bytes, buffer and wait until it reaches 517 bytes, or perform a timeout check.